# Cast relatives classes to each other which has common parent class

Tags: c++, casting

I have classes DBGameAction and ServerGameAction which has common parent class GameAction. Classes DBGameAction and ServerGameAction it's a API for safety  working with entity GameAction from different part of program.

My question is: is it normal at first create DBGameAction entity and then  cast it to the ServerGameAction entity? Or maybe it's a wrong program design?

My program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class GameAction
{
protected:
        /* Need use mutex or something else for having safety access to this entity */
        unsigned int cost;
        unsigned int id;
        std::vector<std::string> players;
        GameAction(){}
public:
        unsigned int getCost() const
        {
                return cost;
        }
};

class DBGameAction : public GameAction
{
public:
        void setCost(unsigned int c)
        {
                cost = c;
        }
        void setId(unsigned int i)
        {
                id = i;
        }
};

class ServerGameAction : public GameAction
{
        ServerGameAction(){}
public:
        void addPlayer(std::string p)
        {
                players.push_back(p);
        }
    std::string getLastPlayer() const
    {
            return players.back();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        DBGameAction *dbga = 0;
        ServerGameAction *sga = 0;

        try {
                dbga = new DBGameAction;
        } 
        catch(...) /* Something happens wrong! */
        {
                return -1;
        }

        sga = reinterpret_cast<ServerGameAction*>(dbga);

        sga->addPlayer("Max");
        dbga->setCost(100);

        std::cout << dbga->getCost() << std::endl;
        std::cout << sga->getLastPlayer() << std::endl;

        delete dbga;
        sga = dbga = 0;

        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The methods of `DBGameAction` are not in the vtable of `ServerGameAction` and vice versa. You would need an instance of a type derived from both, `DBGameAction` and `ServerGameAction`.

Comment: It is a wrong program design if I am getting the design correctly. If ServerGameAction is the "runtime" version of the class and you want a "persisted" version of the class,  it would be better to have a PersistedGameAction inheriting from ServerGameAction. You use the ServerGameAction throughout the code and you use the PersistedGameAction on load/save.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong program design.

Is there a reason why you are not creating GameAction variables which you then downcast to DBGameAction and ServerGameAction?

Comment: Because only Database module can create new game action as DBGameAction entity. Another classes has private constructors (i have updated my code).

Comment: I can remove GameAction class and use DBGameAction class as parent class for others classes, then i can do downcast to the child classes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used reinterpret_cast in many occasions but I am sure it shouldn't be used this way. You should try to find a better design for the interface of your classes. Someone who uses your classes, doesn't have a way to know that he needs to do this sort of castings to add a player.

You have to ask yourself, if adding a player is an operation that only makes sense for ServerGameActions or for DBGameActions too. If it makes sense to add players to DBGameActions, then AddPlayer should be in the interface of DBGameAction too. Then you will not need these casts. Taking it one step further, if it is an operation that makes sense for every possible GameAction you may ever have, you can put it in the interface of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar pattern effectively in the past, but it is a little different than most interface class setups. Instead of having a consistent interface that can trigger appropriate class-specific methods for accomplishing similar tasks on different data types, this provides two completely different sets of functionality which each have their own interface, yet work on the same data layout.

The only reason I would pull out this design is for situations where the base class is data-only and shared between multiple libraries or executables. Then each lib or exe defines a child class which houses all the functionality that it's allowed to use on the base data. This way you can, for example, build your server executable with all kinds of nice extra functions for manipulating game data that the client isn't allowed to use, and the server-side functionality doesn't get built into the client executable. It's much easier for a game modder to trigger existing, dormant functionality than to write and inject their own.

The main part of your question about casting directly between the child classes is making us worry, though. If you find yourself wanting to do that, stop and rethink. You could theoretically get away with the cast as long as your classes stay non-virtual and the derived classes never add data members (the derived classes can't have any data for what you're trying to do anyway, due to object slicing), but it would be potentially dangerous and, most likely, less readable code. As @dspfnder was talking about, you would want to work with base classes for passing data around and down-cast on-demand to access functionality.

With all that said, there are many ways to isolate, restrict, or cull functionality. It may be worth reworking your design with functionality living in friend classes instead of child classes; that would require much less or no casting.

Comment: So i think in that case using friend classes is better way than using inheritance with casting